# Need a dashed line before and after some text html

Tags: html

In my website I need some text and dashed line before and after it. SOmething like:

-------------------Image Width(100px)--------------------------

Can someone help me in accomplishing this. I tried googling but I could not find anything.
There are full dashed lines/lines in borders, but nothing like this.

Comment: why dont just use minus sign(-----------------) ?

Comment: just a question what practical use did u get out of it ?  would luv to know where and why you would do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set up a container and create a `<div>` that sits in the middle with a dashed border.

See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/laucheukhim/k5afz/2/).

```html
<div class='container'>
    <img src='http://dummyimage.com/100/000/fff' />  
    <div class='line'></div>
</div>
```

```css
.container {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}

.line {
    border-top: 1px dashed #000;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    z-index: -2;
}
```

Similarly for text, give it some background and padding and you are good to go.

```html
<div class='container'>
    <span class='text'>some text</span>
    <div class='line'></div>
</div>
```

```css
.text {
    background-color: #FFF;
    padding: 0 3px;
}
```